# Finding which <Option> is selected in <select> (without JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I have the following Element:

```
<select id="color" name="colorId" class="btn secondary">
    <option value="347366" selected="selected">Purple</option>
    <option value="56634">White</option>
</select>
```

And I want to find which option is selected:

The following give me only the default:

```
document.querySelector('#color option[selected="selected"]')
```

(I know how to do it with JQuery but, I can't use jQuery or any other similar library)

Comment: Can you use the normal DOM, ie `document.getElementById('color')`, or do you have to use `css-selectors`?

Comment: I can use both, does it matter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In plain javascript:

```
var select = document.getElementById('color');
var currentOpt = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
```

JsBin example: http://jsbin.com/ogunet/1/edit (open your js console)

Comment: I think Guy wants to know if there is a way to do it using css-selectors.

Answer (score 32):

Use the :checked selector.  This applies to checkbox, radio, and select

```
document.querySelector('#color option:checked')
```

for the node

```
document.querySelector('#color option:checked').value
```

for the value

Comment: This answer is best one.  I had gotten to the following:
("#color").selectedOptions[0].value but it's not as clean as this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will return selected option value and text both.. Hope this will work for u ..

Cheers

```
var elt = document.getElementById('color');

 // get option selected
    var option = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
    var optionText = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the [`<select>` DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement) element using `getElementById()` and take its parameter [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement):

```
var select = document.getElementById( 'color' ),
    selIndex = select.selectedIndex;,
    selElement = select.getElementsByTagName( 'option' )[ selIndex ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `querySelectorAll` not `querySelector`

```
document.querySelectorAll('option:checked')[0].innerText
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('option:checked')[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

[selectedOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) is a valid option when looking to get back the selected option(s) from a select element

a demo from the documentation:

```js
let orderButton = document.getElementById("order");
let itemList = document.getElementById("foods");
let outputBox = document.getElementById("output");

orderButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let collection = itemList.selectedOptions; // <-- used here
  let output = "";

  for (let i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
    if (output === "") {
      output = "Your order for the following items has been placed: ";
    }
    output += collection[i].label;

    if (i === (collection.length - 2) && (collection.length < 3)) {
      output +=  " and ";
    } else if (i < (collection.length - 2)) {
      output += ", ";
    } else if (i === (collection.length - 2)) {
      output += ", and ";
    }
  }

  if (output === "") {
    output = "You didn't order anything!";
  }

  outputBox.innerHTML = output;
}, false);
```

```html
<label for="foods">What do you want to eat?</label><br>
<select id="foods" name="foods" size="7" multiple>
  <option value="1">Burrito</option>
  <option value="2">Cheeseburger</option>
  <option value="3">Double Bacon Burger Supreme</option>
  <option value="4">Pepperoni Pizza</option>
  <option value="5">Taco</option>
</select>
<br>
<button name="order" id="order">
  Order Now
</button>
<p id="output">
</p>
```